# Looking for a Continuous Integration Engine that can handle both Java and C/C++

Tags: continuous-integration

Can anybody recommend a continuous integration engine (like Apache Continuum or Jenkins) that can execute traditional makefiles (GNU Make) along with maven-based Java builds?

I'm working with a code base that is mixed, and where Java calls C through JNI and vice-versa.

Any suggestions? Any experiences performing continuous integration in a mixed environment?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at [jenkins](http://jenkins-ci.org/).  When I was using it, previously as [hudson](http://hudson-ci.org/), it was fairly extensible and allowed you to run terminal programs. You should be able to call up gnu make to build what you need to.